# DDMS for netbeans

Tags: android, ddms

How do I install "Dalvik Debug Monitor Server (DDMS)" for netbeans? Is there any plugin available for it?

Any pointers would be quite helpful.

Peter

Comment: is there a specific reason you wanna use netbeans insteado of eclipse?

Comment: @softarn: I'm using Linux/Ubuntu..

Comment: @Necronet I'm using Linux/Ubuntu.. I couldn't install/run android applications in Eclipse.. so have to use Netbeans 6.8 :(

Comment: well i suggest you just give it a try to eclipse ADT is a complete IDE for android developement it can help you out quite a lot.... maybe you can post an question on SO so we can help you...

Comment: @Necronet Thanks.. Will try it out tomorrow and let you know in case of any issues.

Comment: Please mark an answer as accepted. And yes, try reinstalling eclipse if "eclipse didn't work" is the reason you're not using it.

Comment: @softarn when I vote up an answer it says "Vote Up requires 15 reputation".. What should I do to mark an answer as accepted?

Comment: @peter: it's right under the vote down button

Answer (score 5):

DDMS comes with the SDK is not ADT specific so what you can basicly is:

1. Open a command Line (Linux, Window or MAC)
2. Go to android-sdk-directory/(platform-)tools/
3. Run ddms command.

[image]

**Edit:**

Lately android team decided to replace the "ddms" command with "monitor" this comes with other tools like the hierarchy viewer,Pixel Perfect, and Tracer for OpenGL ES within the same interface, just open a new perspective similar as eclipse does and you can enjoy each one of them.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the Android SDK and execute the DDMS independently.

Answer (score 0):

Talking about plugins: part of the functionality of DDMS is exposed in NBAndroid - http://www.nbandroid.org/

-Radim